# Displaying a CGContextRef

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d

How can I draw a `CGContextRef` created with `CGBitmapContextCreate()` to a NSView?

Should I convert it to a image first? If that's the case, wouldn't it be an expensive operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I convert it to a image first?

Yes. You can use `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`, then use that to draw into the graphics context from `drawRect:`.

> If that's the case, wouldn't it be an expensive operation?

`CGBitmapContext`->`CGImage` one option among multiple - use the best for the task. If you make good design decisions, it's rarely an obstacle.

`CGImage`, `NSImage`, and `UIImage` are immutable. They avoid copying you might expect when they are created.

Larger images can obviously consume a good amount of memory, and it can be expensive to draw the image to the bitmap, and then to draw the image at a size other than its native size.

Reuse the images you create, and hold on to them appropriately. Profile now and then to see how things are going.